# Why might a C++ compiler duplicate a function exit basic block?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, compiler-optimization

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
int* find_ptr(int* mem, int sz, int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (mem[i] == val) { 
            return &mem[i];
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

[GCC on -O3](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int*+find_ptr(int*+mem,+int+sz,+int+val)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+sz%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++if+(mem%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+val)+%7B+%0A++++++++++++return+%26mem%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+nullptr%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.83717387205933,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'169')),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnative',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:49.162826127940676,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) compiles this to:

```
find_ptr(int*, int, int):
        mov     rax, rdi
        test    esi, esi
        jle     .L4                  # why not .L8?
        lea     ecx, [rsi-1]
        lea     rcx, [rdi+4+rcx*4]
        jmp     .L3
.L9:
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     rax, rcx
        je      .L8
.L3:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        jne     .L9
        ret
.L8:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.L4:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

In this assembly, the blocks with labels `.L4` and `.L8` are identical. Would it not be better to rewrite jumps to `.L4` to `.L8` and drop `.L4`? I thought this might be a bug, but [clang](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int*+find_ptr(int*+mem,+int+sz,+int+val)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+sz%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++if+(mem%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+val)+%7B+%0A++++++++++++return+%26mem%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+nullptr%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.83717387205933,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'169')),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnative',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:49.162826127940676,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) *also* duplicates the `xor`-`ret` sequence back to back. However, [ICC](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int*+find_ptr(int*+mem,+int+sz,+int+val)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+sz%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++if+(mem%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+val)+%7B+%0A++++++++++++return+%26mem%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+nullptr%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.83717387205933,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc191,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'169')),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnative',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+19.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:49.162826127940676,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) and [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int*+find_ptr(int*+mem,+int+sz,+int+val)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+sz%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++if+(mem%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+val)+%7B+%0A++++++++++++return+%26mem%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+nullptr%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.83717387205933,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_20_x64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'169')),options:/O2,source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x64+msvc+v19.20+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:49.162826127940676,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) each take a pretty different approach.

Is this an optimization in this case and, if not, are there times when it *would* be? What is the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: i think this is due to phi condition that is generated at end. It looks like phi instruction has 3 possible control path/inputs followed by ret instruction.  check out IR. Not bug for sure.

Comment: @MaheshAttarde If it is true, it is a bug of the low-level optimizer.

Comment: A small discovery: [setting `-mno-avx`](https://godbolt.org/z/BAIxpU) drops the duplicated block on GCC (but not on clang).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/A2_1-S @YSC checkout line 38 and flow of values

Comment: I've see multiple `ret`s like this quite a few times, although not exactly with xor like this but still redundant when you can just use the same ret for all code paths

Comment: @phuclv - I have too. In one bit of code, I saw clang duplicate the end block a full _five_ times. I can't post that code here, so I found a dead-simple example that displayed the behavior.

Comment: Code duplication is sometimes useful to unconditionally jump to an address computed from a run-time value, when multiple values should be treated the same way. But it isn't the case here I think.

Comment: @YSC: You're right this isn't for a computed jump, it's just a fairly common missed optimization in gcc where it apparently fails to look for identical basic blocks that return and merge them.  It's not rare to see crap like this in gcc's asm output, unfortunately.  (And also clang sometimes.)

Comment: @AlexReinking: that's really odd, nice discovery that `-mtune=skylake` merges the blocks, but enabling AVX breaks it again.  You could dig deeper if you look at GCC's GIMPLE or RTL with `-fdump-tree-...` options after certain optimization passes: Godbolt has UI for that, in the `+` dropdown -> tree / RTL output.  But **IMO just report this MCVE to gcc's bugzilla with keyword missed-optimization**.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- other way 'round :) It's `-mno-avx` (disabling) that fixes it.

Comment: @AlexReinking: You used `-march=native` on Godbolt, which sets `-mtune=skylake-avx512` and enables AVX + AVX512 + etc. (because it runs on a `-march=skylake-avx512` CPU).  With that + `-mno-avx`, the problem goes away.  But more simply, just set the tuning option without any arch options.  But then introducing `-mavx` or changing to `-march` instead of `-mtune` enables AVX, re-creating the missed optimization with totally different tuning+arch options from baseline `gcc -O3` with the default `-mtune=generic`

Comment: Interesting that enabling/disabling AVX can break or fix it depending on the other flags...

Comment: `-Os` also helps. It appears that the duplication happens during expansion (gimple->rtl).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is always a missed optimizations.  Having both return-0 paths use the same basic block would be pure win on all microarchitectures that current compilers care about.**

But unfortunately this missed-optimization is not rare with gcc.  Often it's a separate bare `ret` that gcc conditionally branches to, instead of branching to a `ret` in another existing path.  (x86 doesn't have a conditional `ret`, so simple functions that don't need any stack cleanup often just need to branch to a `ret`.
Often functions this small would get inlined in a complete program, so maybe it doesn't hurt a lot in real life?)

CPUs ([since Pentium Pro if not earlier](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/)) have a return-address predictor stack that easily predicts the branch target for `ret` instructions, so there's not going to be an effect from one `ret` instruction more often returning to one caller and another ret more often returning to another caller.  It doesn't help branch prediction to separate them and let them use different entries.

IDK about Pentium 4 and whether the traces in its trace cache follow call/ret.  But fortunately that's not relevant anymore.  The decoded-uop cache in SnB-family and Ryzen is *not* a trace cache; a line/way of uop cache holds uops for a contiguous block of x86 machine code, and unconditional jumps end a uop cache line.  (https://agner.org/optimize/)  So if anything, this could be worse for SnB-family because each return path needs a separate line of the uop cache even though they're each only 2 uops total (xor-zero and ret are both single-uop instructions).

**Report this MCVE to gcc's bugzilla with keyword missed-optimization**: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc

(update: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90178 was reported by the OP.  A fix was attempted, but reverted; for now it's still open.  In this case it seems to be caused by `-mavx`, perhaps some interaction with return paths that need `vzeroupper` or not.)

---

**Cause:**

You can kind of see how it might arrive at 2 exit blocks: compilers normally transform `for` loops into `if(sz>0) { do{}while(); }` if there's a possibility of it needing to run 0 times, like gcc did here.  So there's one branch that leaves the function without entering the loop at all.  But the other exit is from fall through from the loop.  Perhaps before optimizing away some stuff, there was some extra cleanup.  Or just those paths got split up when the first branch was created.

I don't know why gcc fails to notice and merge two identical basic blocks that end with `ret`.

Maybe it only looked for that in some GIMPLE or RTL pass where they weren't actually identical, and only became identical during final x86 code-gen.  Maybe after optimizing away save/restore of a register to hold some temporary that it ended up no needing?

You could dig deeper if you look at GCC's GIMPLE or RTL with `-fdump-tree-...` options after certain optimization passes: Godbolt has UI for that, in the `+` dropdown -> tree / RTL output.  https://godbolt.org/z/l9mVlE.  But unless you're a gcc-internals expert and planning to work on a patch or idea to help gcc find this optimization, it's probably not worth your time.

---

Interesting discovery that it only happens with `-mavx` (enabled by `-march=skylake` or directly).  GCC and clang don't know how to auto-vectorize loops where the trip count is not known before the first iteration.  e.g. search loops like this or `memchr` or `strlen`.  So IDK why AVX even makes a difference at all.

(Note that the C abstract machine never reads `mem[i]` beyond the search point, and those elements might not actually exist.  e.g. there's no UB if you passed this function a pointer to the last `int` before an unmapped page, and `sz=1000`, as long as `*mem == val`.  So to auto-vectorize without `int mem[static sz]` guaranteed object size, the compiler would have to align the pointer...  Not that C11 `int mem[static sz]` would even help; even a static array of compile-time-constant size larger than the max possible trip count wouldn't get gcc to auto-vectorize.)

Comment: +1 I filed it here. Hopefully the devs can shed some more light on the issue. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90178

Comment: Also you have it backwards: `-mtune=skylake` breaks it but _disabling_ AVX merges the blocks.

Comment: @AlexReinking: like I explained in comments on the question, `-march` and `-mtune` are not the same thing. https://godbolt.org/z/tkcNn- For the record for future readers, we see this bug both with `-O3` (with the default `-mtune=generic`) and with `-O3 -mtune=skylake -mavx`.  (But not with `-O3 -mtune=skylake`).

Comment: Devs seem to be treating this as a bug, so your answer is correct! Accepted.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Oops, I did have it partially backwards with gcc options.  I was thinking that bare `-O3` showed the bug, but it doesn't.  It's purely `-mavx` that causes the problem, whether you enable that via `-march=skylake` or directly.  `tune=skylake` or not is irrelevant.

Comment: The real question is why did it generate them both in the first place? Straightforward code generation would have only generated one.

Comment: @user207421: yeah, it's non-obvious.  My guess is that gcc was assuming that it might need to allocate some stack space or save/restore a register in the path that entered the loop.  Straightforward code-gen includes turning a `for` into an `if(sz>0) { do{}while(); }` to create a normal asm loop with the loop branch at the bottom.  But good point, updated my answer to include that.